# Convert Query in Mysal to SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using Entity Framework i got a error  '"The query syntax is not valid. Near term ':', line 1, column 109." from system .data.entity.sqlserver. so please tell me to convert below query in SQL

```
SELECT Agentid,year(Date_Time) as Year,monthname(Date_Time) as  Month,SUM(AmountRecevied) as Amount,@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS Rank FROM collection_master,  
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r GROUP BY AgentID,year(Date_Time),monthname(Date_Time) ORDER BY  
    Amount DESC


  Agentid         logintime             AmountReceived

1        2013/10/01 00:10:10         10000
 1        2013/10/01 17:23:10         200
 1        2013/10/01 00:30:41         3000
2        2013/10/02 05:10:52         1000
  3        2013/10/02 09:10:25         2000 
3        2013/10/03 10:10:18         2000
2        2013/10/03 13:10:35         7000
```

I want a query that should display the output as

```
 Agentid    Amount  Rank
1         13200    1
2         8000     2
3         4000     3
```

I had Tried below query not getting expected output please check it once

```
with temp as (
select row_number() over (order by AmountRecevied) as rownum,AgentID,YEAR(Date_Time) as Years,SUM(AmountRecevied) as amount 
from tblcollections  group by CustomerID,AgentID,Date_Time ,AmountRecevied

 select rownum,AgentID,Years,amount from temp
```

Comment: You cant use : to assaign value to a variable.
What would you like to get? What is the pupose of the query?

Comment: please check my eddited question

Comment: SQL Server has real window functions and does not need a hack to generate a rownumber. Check out the `row_number()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job: I cant test it, so pls give it a try.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT Agentid,year(Date_Time) as Year, MONTH(Date_Time) as  Month,SUM(AmountRecevied) as Amount 
FROM collection_master,  
GROUP BY AgentID,year(Date_Time),MONTH(Date_Time) 
) 
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CTE.Amount DESC) AS RANKING
FROM CTE 
Order by RANKING
```

Comment: how to find date in sql

Comment: Date(Date_Time) as days it's showing invalid function

Comment: i want both month and date when tiring for date "error:Operand type clash: timestamp is incompatible with nvarchar"